# SplashScreen View to TabView View in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, splash-screen, tabview

I am having difficulty transitioning from my SplashScreen View to my TabView View.  I found that I could transition any of my other views, but crash occurs with transition to TabView.

**SplashScreen code** (from youTube video)

```
struct SplashScreenView: View {
    
    @State private var isActive = false
    @State private var size = 0.8
    @State private var opacity = 0.5
    
    var body: some View {
        
        if isActive == true {
            TabView()
        }
        else {
            VStack {
                VStack{
                    Image(systemName: "hare.fill")
                        .font(.system(size: 80))
                        .foregroundColor(.red)
                    Text("IALVS App")
                        .font(Font.custom("Baskerville-Bold", size: 26))
                        .foregroundColor(.black.opacity(0.80))
                }
                .scaleEffect(size)
                .opacity(opacity)
                .onAppear{
                    withAnimation(.easeIn(duration: 1.2)) {
                        self.size = 0.9
                        self.opacity = 1.0
                    }
                }
            }
            .onAppear {
                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2.0) {
                    withAnimation {                        
                        self.isActive = true
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**TabView** code

```
struct MembersTabView: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var modelMember:MemberModel
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            
            TabView {
                
                MembersListView()
                    .tabItem {
                        Image(systemName: "person.2")
                    }
                
                MapView()
                    .tabItem {
                        Image(systemName: "map")
                    }
                
                MainCalcView()
                    .tabItem {
                        Image(systemName: "wrench.adjustable.fill")
                    }
            }
        }
        
    }
}
```

Tried transitioning to other views.  Worked fine.

Comment: Where are you setting the `MemberModel`?

Comment: Where does this crash(What line)? What is the exact error message?

Comment: Well... the issue appears to have solved itself.  While the preview continues to crash, the simulator now works just fine.  I have made no changes.